# How to make an algorithm with worse case O(n^2) for searching 2 lists and adding common values to a 3rd?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I need help making a pseudocode for an algorithm that takes two lists of integers, and creates a list consisting of those integers that appear in both lists (each integer on the final list should appear only once). The algorithm needs to achieve an asymptotically better worst case performance than Θ(n<sup>2</sup>), where n is the sum of the lengths of the two input lists.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not confident in it:

- Start with two lists, a and b. The resulting list will be c.
- Sort list b using the merge sort algorithm.
- Starting with index i=0, iterate through list a.
- Use binary search algorithm to search list b for the value at a[i]
- if a[i] is found in b, and a[i] is not in c.. append a[i] to c.

Comment: You can do this in O(n).

Comment: Your algorithm seems ok, is it the complexity you aren't sure about?

Comment: @BenVoigt yeah it is. I don't really understand how to justify the Big-O time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Sort both lists. Complexity order of this step is **n log n**. Use [quick sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).
2. Compare sorted lists and find common elements. Complexity order is of this step is **n**.

```c++
int i = 0, j = 0;
while ((j < b.size()) && (i < a.size()))
{
   if (a[i] < b[j])
   {
       i++;
       continue;
   }
   if (a[i] > b[j])
   {
       j++;
       continue;
   }
   // if we are here, a[i] == b[j]
   c.push_back(a[i]);
   i++;
   j++;
   // skip identical elements
   while ((i < a.size()) && (a[i-1]==a[i]))
   {
       i++;
   }
   while ((j < b.size()) && (b[j-1]==b[j]))
   {
       j++;
   }
}
return c;
```

Total complexity order is **n log n**.

Comment: @DaveGalvin: maps and hash maps do sorting internally. Would you detail your suggested algo so that we can see what you mean?

Comment: And my suggested algorithm is below.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in linear time with a map (aka hash table) or Bloom filter to keep track of what you've seen. I.e., for each elt in list A, map[elt]=1. Then, for each elt in list B, check if it's a key in your map. If it is, delete the key from the map and add the elt to your output list.

Comment: The map does the sorting for you. Complexity of what you code is indeed linear, but map has to do sorting by key when adding elements. Complexity of this sorting will be n log n or worse.

Comment: @YuliaV: I think he's recommending a hash table, which may approach O(n).

Comment: @BenVoigt: what would be the comparison operator for this hash table (I presume its C++ is hash_map, is not it)?

Comment: @YuliaV: The best standard container would be `std::unordered_set`.

Comment: @YuliaV: Agreed.  It really depends on how detailed the pseudocode must be.  If you can use operations like `insert (a[i]) into hash table`, then it isn't too bad.  If you need to show the collision resolution logic and everything, it would get very complex.

Comment: A Bloom filter would be a particularly bad choice here, as there is the possibility of a false positive. And you probably wouldn't want to delete an item from the map when you find a duplicate. If you did that, then you'd end up with duplicates in your output if you saw the same item again (i.e. the second list contained the item more than once).

Comment: @JimMischel It depends on the characteristics of the lists. Say the lists are both large, but their intersection is small. You can use a Bloom filter to be space efficient, and then go through the intersection with a map to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

```
List a

List b

List c

Node an = a.first

Node bn

while an != null

    bn = b.first
    while bn != null

        if an.data == bn.data
            c.add(data)

        bn = bn.next
    endwhile

    an = an.next
endwhile
```

The complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Note: you can implement an add() method that doesn't allow repeated values